# How can I set the background of a div using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, slick.js

I need to set the background of a div to the image of the post via PHP. I'm using wordpress and have the following code:

```
    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()); ?>

    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('largest'); ?>" class="img-fluid">
```

I want to use this code to set the background of some divs that are on the homepage for design purposes.

I have tried setting it using a styles.php file but I'm either coding it completely wrong or it doesn't work, the code I tried is as follows:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>

.slider-card {
background-image: url(<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()); ?>

<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('largest'); ?>" class="img-fluid">
)
};
```

If there is any way to make it so that the background image for my .slider-card divs can be automatically filled using the user-uploaded image it would be great if someone could teach me!
All help appreciated.

EDIT:

This was the code when I checked it in the browser.

```
url(<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function has_post_thumbnail() in C:xampphtdocsMedia Site WPwp-contentthemesMediaThemestyle.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in <b>C:xampphtdocsMedia Site WPwp-contentthemesMediaThemestyle.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your html and php is wrong.Try this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>

.slider-card {
background-image: url(<?php if (get_the_post_thumbnail() != null){get_the_post_thumbnail();} ?>

}
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('largest'); ?>" class="img-fluid">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue but I have found what seems like an error: url(<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function has_post_thumbnail() in C:xampphtdocsMedia Site WPwp-contentthemesMediaThemestyle.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in <b>C:xampphtdocsMedia Site WPwp-contentthemesMediaThemestyle.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />

Answer (score 0):

1st you should know is that [has_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) works only inside of [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), so from the code you shared there is no way the function to work like this. Outside the loop you SHOULD pass the current post id and then use [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) instead, so you pass 2 parameters there - id and size:

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail($page_id)): ?>
<img src="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail_url($page_id, 'largest'); ?>" class="img-fluid">
<?php endif; ?>
```